# Recover files from previous git commit after git rm

Tags: git, github

I'm in a really bad situation. I wrote a lot of scripts for a project and accidentally deleted them.

I have 3 branches: master, Dev, App

I develop on the Dev branch, keep a working copy on master, and write application scripts in App. I merged Dev to master, then merged master to App. But when I did I forgot that I had deleted all my app scripts from master and Dev. So I blindly deleted all of my application scripts in App. Now, I want to go back and get those files.

To go back a commit I used

```
git revert HEAD~1
```

I then tried

```
git rm app_*
```

to untrack the files. But that deleted them all from my folder. And now I can't find them in any commit. How can I get these files back??

Comment: You can try reverting back into the old revision. use this command to see the revisions for particular file > git log --oneline <filename>. You can revert to old revision using this command > git checkout #oldrevision#.

Comment: It was a lot of files. Like 40. Long names. I don't remember any of them.

Comment: you can do >>  git log --oneline app_*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the branch you want to fix.

```
git checkout App
```

Find the commit **before** the files were deleted

```
git log --stat
```

Remember that SHA and reset to that SHA.

```
git reset --hard bada55
```

Repeat for the other branches. You can see what you did and the SHA of what happened using the `git reflog` command. Helps find points of time that are not on the current branch history.

Comment: Thank you!!! The stat thing is what I was looking for. I kept looking at my log thinking "I have no idea where these files are"

Comment: Yeah, `git log` just shows the commit message. `git log --stat` shows the filenames and `git log --patch` shows the full diff. You can also filter logs by file/directory `git log -- my/path` you can search commit messages with `git log --grep` and you can search diffs that match a term `git log -Sterm`. You can combine all those too (`git log --stat --patch -SmyFunction --grep Refactor -- app/src`)

Answer (score 0):

git checkout [name of file]

or

git reset head --hard